# Laravel file extension for the array values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get the file extension of the files from the multiple file input array.

I tried to use `File::extension()` but it expects a string and I have an array.

I don't need this value for the validation so I can't use Laravel validation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get the file extension of the files from the multiple
>   file input array.

Then loop over the `$_FILES` array.

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $file) {
    $extensions[$key] = \File::extension($file['name']);
}
```

The above presumes no fancy/opinionated $_FILES structure mutations ;p

Answer (score 0):

The best way I use,

```
foreach ( $request->file ( 'attachment' ) as $attachment ) {
            $orignalName = $attachment->getClientOriginalName ();
            $mimeType = $attachment->getMimeType () ;
    }
```

If you are using Laravel's default file upload.